# OpenCV ConvertTo CV_32SC1 from CV_8UC1

Tags: opencv, c++11

Hello I am using opencv in version 3.4 and want to read an image (*.pgm) and then convert it to `CV_32SC1`. Therefore I use the following code (part):

```
img = imread(f, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
img.convertTo(imgConv, CV_32SC1);
```

The problem is the following, all pixels are converted to zero, and I don't understand why. I'm checking by (and `imshow("Image", imgConv);`)

```
cout << static_cast<int>(img.at<uchar>(200,100));
cout << static_cast<int32_t>(imgConv.at<int32_t>(200,100)) << endl;
```

In my example this results in

74
74

I tested several points of the image, all pixels are simply the same, but shouldn't them being converted automatically to the 32 bit range, or do I have to manage that manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manage that manually. This is why `cv::Mat::convertTo()` has another parameter, a scale. For instance, if you want to convert from `CV_8U` to `CV_32F` you'd typically

```
img.convertTo(img2, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);
```

to scale to the typical float-valued range. I'm not sure what your expected range for `CV_32SC1` is, since you're going from unsigned to signed, but just add the scale factor you feel is right.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `imgLeft.convertTo(imgLeft, CV_32SC1, static_cast<int32_t>(4294967296/255));` then? (2^32) = 4294967296. However since it is signed 32bit I needed to add a delta of -2147483647 to get the numbers right. Is the cv::imshow not able to print CV_32SC1 images?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. I never use 32-bit integer images, especially not signed. Only ones I'm using is `CV_32F` (usually with range 0 to 1), `CV_8U` obviously, and the occasional `CV_16S` or `CV_16U`, but then these are usually 12-bit images with a range from 0 to 65535 or -32768 to 32767. Using any integral type in its full range except 8 bit is something I never did so far, so I'm not sure why you would and what range you'd use and why.

Comment: I don't want to, but I got some algorithm which requires this format :-) So thank ou for clarifying that it is my task to ensure correct value range, I thought opencv would do that for me.

Comment: how do I check whether it is 8 bit or 32 bit?